# Custom controller class name in Code Igniter

Tags: codeigniter

How do make CodeIgniter correctly load controller classes if I want to name them [name]_Controller rather than just [name]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to write your own router-class, [in the documentation is a great explanation for that](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/core_classes.html) task!

This could be a good starting point:
https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/system/core/Router.php#L394